# Installed ubuntu,GRUB missing and cann't find ubuntu to enter manually

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I installed(dual booted) Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on my dell inspiron machine in UEFI mode(with secure boot:off) along side windows 10.during the installation it said GRUB is installed but when i restarted after the installation GRUB didn't appear,it directly loaded win10.I searched for Ubuntu in UEFI options(in  Bios)
to find whether it installed or not.Nowhere i found ubuntu, i tried changing into other bios modes(like LEGACY and UEFI with secure boot:on) sothat i can enter ubuntu manually.I cleared the hard disk partition and installed once again.but that didn't work.I used a USB stick booted using UNETBOOTIN once and POWERISO in the second time.I followed all the instructions to install.
                          Totally i didn't find GRUB and Ubuntu(cann't even enter maually) in all the modes.

NOTE:One of the Hard disk partitions showing that it is allocated for                 something(may be ubuntu) other than windows.I am unable enter the partition but i can format it.

Comment: Better to have posted this first, before clearing disk. So not sure where you are at. Generally Dell just works. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Try using boot-repairdisc. It has never failed me. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: Post the URL that Boot Repair produces for *you* -- the link you posted is to the generic Boot Repair instructions, which is unhelpful for diagnostics.

Comment: Thanks for the support.I didn't want GRUB.so,I installed ubuntu in LEGACY mode after that installed windows in UEFI mode.No problems It's working fine.